# Evilness of document.write in javascript

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, document.write

recently i have seen following error in jsfiddle `document.write is disallowed in JSFiddle envioriment and might break your fiddle`. Why JSfiddle has banned `document.write`? What are the major side effects of using this? and what are the best alternatives of this?

Comment: `document.write` can have problems with race conditions and, if the document is finished being written, will trigger `document.open` - clearing the whole page of all _HTML_. Alternatives? Use _DOM methods_ such as `appendChild`.

Comment: So if added the document.write("something") in my code, it will auto trigger the document.open and my whole code will be erased?

Comment: You may find it helpful to read the MDN page on this method https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write